# Uncaught SyntaxError Unexpected token < in JSON

Tags: javascript, ajax

I'm trying to do an exercise and I get a problem, when I execute the code, it show me this message:

```
VM45:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
    at Object.success (app.js:88)
    at fire (jquery.js:3268)
    at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (jquery.js:3398)
    at done (jquery.js:9305)
    at XMLHttpRequest.<anonymous> (jquery.js:9548)
```

I was looking but I can't see the fault. I downloaded jquery from development and I put like jquery.js and I'm using a downloaded bootstrap.

I was checking the line 88 but I don't see the problem... I've tried to see if I have a problem with the const but I don't see anything.

```
// Get a Single Task by Id 
    $(document).on('click', '.task-item', (e) => {
      const element = $(this)[0].activeElement.parentElement.parentElement;
      const id = $(element).attr('taskId');
      $.post('task-single.php', {id}, (response) => {
        const task = JSON.parse(response);
        $('#name').val(task.name);
        $('#description').val(task.description);
        $('#taskId').val(task.id);
        edit = true;
      });
      e.preventDefault();
    });
```

The line is 88 is:  `const task = JSON.parse(response);`

I want to correct this mistake, because I can't edit my tasks if I have it.

Comment: What's the JSON returned from the AJAX?

Comment: what is `response`?

Comment: `task-single.php` appears to be responding with HTML (or something like it), not JSON. Check your browser's _Network_ console for the actual response

Comment: Hi Jack, It's an application for tasks, and I have a function called fetchTasks(), this function has a $.ajax where I've function that obtain the tasks and write the response in a table, I have id, name and description. In this section especifically i'm trying to obtain the id of the table and take the value to apply SQL code in the php page.

Comment: No way!! Phil, you're better than my eyes hahaha, I had the problem in the php page, I had " $result = mysqli_query($connection, $query);
  if(!result) {
    die('Query Failed'. mysqli_error($connection));
  }" and I forgot the $ in result